# Tensor product of representations on a compact quantum group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, qa.quantum-algebra, c-star-algebras, quantum-groups, tensor-products

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a $C^*$-algebraic compact quantum group (in the sense of Woronowicz) with function algebra $(C(\mathbb{G}), \Delta)$.

Let $X \in M(B_0(H)\otimes C(\mathbb{G}))$ and $Y \in M(B_0(K)\otimes C(\mathbb{G}))$ be representations of $\mathbb{G}$ and define their tensor product by
$$X \boxtimes Y := X_{13} Y_{23} \in M(B_0(H)\otimes B_0(K)\otimes C(\mathbb{G})) = M(B_0(H\otimes K)\otimes C(\mathbb{G})).$$
It is easily checked that this is a representation of $\mathbb{G}$ on the Hilbert space $H \otimes K$.

Perhaps a somewhat vague question, but is there a fast way to check that a representation on $H \otimes K$ is the tensor product of two representations?

Compare with the following: Let $Z$ be a representation of $\mathbb{G}$ on $H \oplus K$. Then $Z = X \boxplus Y$ if the natural inclusions
$$H \hookrightarrow H \oplus K, \quad K \hookrightarrow H \oplus K$$
are intertwiners from $X$ to $Z$ resp. from $Y$ to $Z$. I'm looking for something similar for the tensor product.